# Boxing movie with a hero recently released from prison

Tags: identify-this-movie

I don't remember any actors or exactly when the movie was released, but I remember seeing this movie on Netflix in 2013-2014.

- Movies was released between 2004-2015
- I think the movie cover has some green in it with some people.
- It's a boxing movie.
- The main actor gets out of jail and moves into a halfway house for
  released prisoners.
- He gets a job at a store where they sell alcohol.
- His friend bet on who is going to win at the local boxing ring.
- His friend wants the main actor to win.
- Also his friend owes some guy money and gets kidnapped.
- Main actor tries to help his friend and makes a deal with the
  kidnapper that he will win a number of boxing matches.
- There are some dirty cops.
- At the end there is a big national boxing match that the main actor
  wins, but when the match is over the main actor is confronted by
  the dirty cop, and the dirty cop tries to kill him but is stopped.

I have tried:

- Searching for boxing movies that have been on Netflix.
- Looking through images of covers of boxing movies from 2005-2015.
- Looking through lists of boxing movies.

But with no luck.

Comment: "this is everything that I remember" Heh, you should see some of the other ID questions we get... ;) You remembered quite a lot. Thanks for the detailed question!

Comment: Oh okay :D Thank you so much for helping me. I have tried finding it for so many days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds a lot like [The Philly Kid](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1937506/combined) from 2012.

> An attempt to purchase beer becomes a nightmare for underage friends Chase, Jake and Dillon when Chase ends up dead, Jake gets shot in the back, and Dillon - a championship wrestler - goes to prison for manslaughter. Released after ten years, Dillon's greeted by Jake, who lines him up with a job and introduces him to the world of minor league MMA fighting. Due to Jake's outstanding gambling debt, Dillon agrees to three fights to cover it and literally save Jake's life but finds himself caught between gangsters, dirty cops, a shady promoter, a snide parole officer and Jake's disapproving sister.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: @Walt: i'm impressed how many questions you answer .. would be cool to get the background info too, how you found it. not just here, i'm a regular reader! :) take care!

Comment: Thanks. :) I'm afraid it doesn't really make for a compelling story... I just know most of them (and have seen probably half of them). For the rest I mainly just use Google and IMDb, if they sound interesting.

Comment: Just watched the movie, i would just like to thank you again!